# java.sql.SQLException: No database selected - but it is in the URL

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I've been researching this for hours and understand that the database schema name should be in the URL. I have it in the URL, but I am still getting this error.

I am using Eclipse and Tomcat v9.0 and sql-connector version 8.0.28.

I have ensured to add the SQL connector everywhere, such as the Build Path, in the Tomcat Folder, in the Tomcat Server configuration, and I am still unable to access it.

In my web.xml I have the following:

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>dbURL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309/logs</param-value>
    </context-param>
      
    <dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my DBConnection class, I am able to successfully connect to the database with the following code:

```
package com.algonquin.loggy.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class DBConnection {

    // Database Schema
    // CREATE DATABASE loggy DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
    // CREATE TABLE logs (uuid CHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, title CHAR(128),
    // content TEXT, createTimestamp Date);

    private static final String dbUser = "root";
    private static final String dbPassword = "mypassword";
    private static final String conString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3309//logs";


    
    public static Connection getConnectionToDatabase() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        
        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // get hold of the DriverManager
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(conString, dbUser, dbPassword);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("Connection made to DB!");
        }

        return connection;
    }



public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {

    getConnectionToDatabase();
    
    }
}
```

Would greatly appreciate any support that can be given!

Comment: The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html) on the MySQL JDBC URL format shows one `/` character between the host and db name, but you have two such characters. Have you tried it with just one `/`?

Comment: Yes removing the / before the ? worked :) thanks so much!